# Do un-blockable hits count toward the achievement?

Tags: batman-arkham-origins

For the *Point Counter-Point* achievement you have to complete the Deathstroke battle without missing a single counter. But some of Deathstroke's attacks I cannot block no matter how hard I try. No counter icon comes up, and he hits me no matter what and does damage.

So do these hits count toward the achievement? Do I only have to counter the hits that are possible to counter, or am I not allowed to take any damage at all?

Comment: What game mode are you playing in? All attacks should be avoidable, but some, you do not use counter for

Comment: I am playing in the I Am The Night mode.

Comment: You cant really confirm no marker should come up.. but try the double jump vault. Thats usually there for nonblockables

Comment: I watched a gameplay video of the fight in normal mode and no marker came up either. It goes into a short cutscene-type thing so I can't double jump dodge away.

Comment: I recorded a video of the attacks here: https://youtu.be/ISuD4OjkK_Q https://youtu.be/8_EQnNsa-z8 (it got split up into two).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so after a lot of experimenting and practice I finally managed to do the whole battle without taking a single hit! That was one of the most intense battles of my life.

I found that there are two attacks that he performs in his staff form that I thought were unblockable. In one, Slade stands on the ground and hits you three times. I found that with very precise timing, though, you are able to counter that one in between the second and third hit.

In the other attack he hits you three times in quick succession and then does a spin move in the air to deal a fourth blow. The time to counter comes *right* before he lands the fourth blow, when he is finishing his spin in the air.

It turns out these attacks can be countered, but only if they are countered at the *exact right time*. If the counter button is hit any other time during the attack, it becomes impossible to counter and he hits you.

Thanks to @Timelord64 for the help and convincing me that none of the attacks were un-blockable :P